# how to check valid magnet link in php

Tags: php, magnet-uri

Magnet link:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:8fe65e43464debe1bc0961e4656ea780368d4fba&dn=A+Goofy+Movie+%281995%29+720p+HDTVRip+x264+Eng+Subs+%5BDual+Audio%5D+%5BHindi+DD+2.0+-+English+DD+2.0%5D+Exclusive+By+-%3D%21Dr.STAR%21%3D-&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fzer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce
```

My question is how to check this link is valid or in valid in PHP

Sorry but i am new in coding and i dont have much knowledge of coding

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/19707059/3723368

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to verifiy a magnet link (Javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227280/any-way-to-verifiy-a-magnet-link-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

For PHP it can be done like so:

```
$str = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:74651f66e937698dc5ac1e0e252f44795070a7b5&dn=archlinux-2017.03.01-dual.iso&tr=udp://tracker.archlinux.org:6969&tr=http://tracker.archlinux.org:6969/announce';

if(preg_match('/magnet:\?xt=urn:[a-z0-9]+:[a-z0-9]{32,40}/', $str)){
  echo 'valid';
}
```

But this only checks if the format is in order, you don't know if the magnet link will work unless you try it out.

Comment: thank you sir its gives me basic idea to do next things