# Verify magnet link in Python (using regular expressions)?

Tags: python, verification, magnet-uri

### Context

I tried to verify a magnet link using Python. After checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19707059/7437143), I tried to copy the solution to Python using:

```
def verify_magnet_link(magnet_link):
    print(f'magnet_link={magnet_link}')
    pattern='/magnet:\?xt=urn:[a-z0-9]+:[a-z0-9]{32}/i'
    print(f'pattern={pattern}')
    if (re.match(pattern,magnet_link) != None):
        print('Link is valid')
    else:
        print("Magnet link invalid.")
```

I verified the regular expression pattern in Regexr.com on the Ubuntu 22.04 OS magnet link:

```
magnet_link = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:FRVWQWGWDWUVIPKCGGTR3NFRZETEWBUF&dn=ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso&xl=3654957056&tr.1=https%3A%2F%2Ftorrent.ubuntu.com%2Fannounce&tr.2=https%3A%2F%2Ftorrent.ubuntu.com%2Fannounce&tr.3=https%3A%2F%2Fipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com%2Fannounce'

# Specify an output dir
output_dir = "/home/"

verify_magnet_link(magnet_link)
```

However, that returns:

```
None
Magnet link invalid.
```

### Question

How can one verify a magnet link formatting in Python?

Answer (score 1):

The `verify_magnet_link(magnet_link)` function verifies a Python link. If the link is valid, it prints `Magnet link is valid!` otherwise it prints `Magnet link is invalid`.

```py
def verify_magnet_link(magnet_link):
    pattern=re.compile(r"magnet:\?xt=urn:[a-z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}")
    result = pattern.match(magnet_link)
    if result != None:
        print("Magnet link is valid!")
    else:
        print("Magnet link is invalid.")


magnet_link = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:FRVWQWGWDWUVIPKCGGTR3NFRZETEWBUF&dn=ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso&xl=3654957056&tr.1=https%3A%2F%2Ftorrent.ubuntu.com%2Fannounce&tr.2=https%3A%2F%2Ftorrent.ubuntu.com%2Fannounce&tr.3=https%3A%2F%2Fipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com%2Fannounce'

# Specify an output dir
output_dir = "/home/name"

verify_magnet_link(magnet_link)
```

Note that a slight change is implemented w.r.t. to [the original answer in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19707059/7437143), the last `[a-z0-9]` is changed to `[a-zA-Z0-9]` because the `FRVWQWGWDWUVIPKCGGTR3NFRZETEWBUF&` is capitalised. Python did not give a match on the original answer with `a-z0-9`, however, regexr does: regexr.com/6nvl1 . I am not quite sure why this difference in behaviour occurs.